# Unable to Make a Custom ListView Form json Response Application Close Eventually

Tags: java, android, json, listview

These is an interface method in which json response passes as parameter

```
 public void onTransmitionCompleted(String result){

            Employee employee = new Employee();

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

when I want to check my json response data successfull catches in AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setMessage(jsonObject.toString());
alert.show();
```

When I comment AlertDialog and uncomment below code which CustomAdapter the application close eventually iam new in android development and unable to rectify that problem:

```
ArrayList<EmpData> empList = employee.parse(jsonObject);
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.listview,empList);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image: this is my json response]

This is my class that get employee data from json response and make ArrayList
of EmpData class Objects like ArrayList

```
public class Employee {
`I pass my json reponse data to Employee class parse method`
        public ArrayList<EmpData> parse(JSONObject jsonObject){
            JSONArray employee = null;
            try{
                employee = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return getEmployees(employee);
        }
`these method make ArrayList<EmpData> objects from json response`
        private ArrayList<EmpData> getEmployees(JSONArray jEmployees){
            ArrayList<EmpData> empDataList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0 ; i < jEmployees.length() ; i++){
                try {
                    empDataList.add( getEmployeeData((JSONObject) jEmployees.get(i)) );
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return empDataList;
        }
`Here i get inner json object from jsonArray and get employee data in row form`
        private EmpData getEmployeeData(JSONObject jemployee){

            String name,dept,id;
            EmpData empData = new EmpData();

            try {
                id = jemployee.getString("empid");
                name = jemployee.getString("empname");
                dept = jemployee.getString("deptname");
`here i check employee id and set employee pic to the corresponing employee id`
                if (id.toString().equals("2")){
`here iam set employee pic by check it employee id`
                    empData.setImageRespid(R.drawable.arif);                    empData.setDepartment(dept);
                    empData.setName(name);
                }else if(id.toString().equals("4")){
                    empData.setImageRespid(R.drawable.ibad);
                    empData.setDepartment(dept);
                    empData.setName(name);
                }else if (id.toString().equals("16")){
                    empData.setImageRespid(R.drawable.kamal);
                    empData.setDepartment(dept);
                    empData.setName(name);
                }else if (id.toString().equals("11")){
                    empData.setImageRespid(R.drawable.mousa);
                    empData.setDepartment(dept);
                    empData.setName(name);
                }else if (id.toString().equals("15")){
                    empData.setImageRespid(R.drawable.sheriyar);
                    empData.setDepartment(dept);
                    empData.setName(name);
                }else{
                    empData.setImageRespid(R.mipmap.user);
                    empData.setDepartment(dept);
                    empData.setName(name);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            `here i return EmpData object`
            return  empData;
        }
    }
```

This is my EmpData Class:

```
     public class EmpData {

        public int ImageRespid;
        public String Name;
        public String Department;

        public EmpData(){
            this.ImageRespid = 0;
            this.Name = null;
            this.Department = null;
        }

        public EmpData(int imageRespid, String name, String department) {
            ImageRespid = imageRespid;
            Name = name;
            Department = department;
        }
`get image id`
        public int getImageRespid() {
            return ImageRespid;
        }
`set image id` 
        public void setImageRespid(int imageRespid) {
            ImageRespid = imageRespid;
        }
`get employee name`
        public String getName() {
            return Name;
        }
`set employee name`
        public void setName(String name) {
            Name = name;
        }
`get employee department`
        public String getDepartment() {
            return Department;
        }
`set employee department`
        public void setDepartment(String department) {
            Department = department;
        }
    }
```

This is my custom adapter class

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EmpData>{

            Context context;
            int LayoutResourceId; 
            ArrayList<EmpData> data = null; 

`to hold employee ArrayList<EmpData>` 



     public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<EmpData> objects) {
    `Set these field form constructor values`
                super(context, resource, objects);
                this.context = context;
                this.LayoutResourceId = resource;
                this.data = objects; `in here ArrayList<Emp> data comes`
            }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {

                    if (convertView == null) {
`here i convert layout xml`

                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null, true);

                    }
`in here i get employee object from list`
                    EmpData empData = data.get(position);`get cursor position `
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personImg);
                    TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personName);
                    TextView txtDept = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personDept);
                    'In here i set data in my custom layout'
                    txtName.setText(empData.getName());
                    txtDept.setText(empData.getDepartment());
                    imageView.setImageResource(empData.getImageRespid());

                    return convertView;
                }               
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am forget to bind `listview` to layout resource id

```
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.emp);
```